# Search a varchar with spaces in range by converting it using to_number

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to search for a number like `61 123456` in a range. This is stored as varchar in db.
I did something like this,

`TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(’61 123456′),'\s') BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(TN_RANGE_STRT,’\s’)) AND TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(TN_RANGE_END,’\s’))`

But, it is not working.

In the DB the range is store as `61 123455-61 123465`

Please help me.

Comment: This looks more like oracle than mysql. If so you should change the tag to attract oracle experts.

Comment: Either mysql or oracle only one database is possible in most of case unless you have extraoridinary setup, please mention the `database name` clearly and also tag it correctly whether `mysql` or `oracle`.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Can you please post some sample data and needed result to clarify your need?

Comment: Start range is 61 123455.. end range is 61 123465.. i want to search '61 123456' and retrieve if anything is present .. i.e basically i want to search the accounts if any present in that range.. but these fields are stored as varchar . so i cant perform directly. i am using to_number to convert and using regexp_replace to ignore the spaces.. but i am missing on something as the result is not coming.

Comment: Please edit the question adding a small set of sample data and needed result for that data. This will both clarify your need and help people to test some code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a string like `'61 123455'` must be converted into the number `61.123.455`, and that the format of ranges is fixed, you may need something like this:

```
with yourTable(range) as (
    select '61 123455-61 123465' from dual union
    select '61 100-61 200' from dual
)
select *
from yourTable
where to_number(replace('61 123456', ' ', '')) between
        to_number(replace(regexp_substr(range, '[0-9 ]*'), ' ', '')) AND
        to_number(replace(regexp_substr(range, '(-)([0-9 ]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 2), ' ', ''))
```